# Integration for a polynomial function xi

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

We have a function
\begin{equation*}
\xi_{k} (x)= \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{j} \frac{x^{2j+1}}{2j+1}\binom{k}{j},
\end{equation*}
Differentiating, we get 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial \xi_{k}}{\partial x} = (1-x^{2})^{k}.
\end{equation*}
Since $\xi_{k}(0)=0$ we get 
\begin{equation*}
\xi_{k}(x)= \int_{0}^{x} (1-t^{2})^{k}  dt = ... = \text{why?}
\end{equation*}
integration by part and set $x=1$, we get $(2k+1)\xi_{k}(1)=2k\xi_{k-1}(1)$.

I can't get the last calculation right, I have hightligted like this "..."

Comment: Did you note that $t^2=1-(1-t^2)$?

Comment: I can't see how it can benefit

Comment: The factor $t^2$ should appear in the integrand after the partial integration. Rewriting it and then splitting the integral would get you close to the mentioned result.

Comment: I had rewritten it so many times, using the hint you gfave me dont fix it, should I use substitution for $u=1-t^2$ ?

Comment: I wrote the details in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the proof of the recurrence relation one has $$\xi_{k}(1)=\int_0^1 (1-t^{2})^{k}\ dt= t(1-t^2)^k\ \Bigg{|}_0^1 + \int_{0}^12kt^2\ (1-t^{2})^{k-1}\ dt=$$ $$=0+2k\int_{0}^11\ (1-t^{2})^{k-1}\ dt -2k\int_{0}^1(1-t^2)\ (1-t^{2})^{k-1}\ dt=2k\xi_{k-1}(1)-2k\xi_{k}(1)$$

Comment: This complete it, thank you!

Comment: How is the first line derived?

Comment: It is the partial integration $\int_0^1f(t)dt=tf(t)\ \Big{|}_0^1-\int_0^1t\frac{df}{dt}\ dt$ with $f(t)=(1-t^2)^k$.

Comment: What rule is this? I never seen this identity before

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts with $v(x)=x$

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something? Why not just take the same route backwards and integrate the binomial expansion using the new variable $t$
$$\frac{d\,\xi_{k}(t)}{dt} =(1-t^{2})^{k}= \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{j} \binom{k}{j}\;t^{2j}$$

$$\xi_{k}(x)= \int_{0}^{x} (1-t^{2})^{k} \, dt =\int_{0}^{x} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{j} \binom{k}{j}\;t^{2j}\,  dt$$

$$\xi_{k} (x)= \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{j} \frac{x^{2j+1}}{2j+1}\binom{k}{j}$$

Comment: Yes I understand this, so letting x=1 I should give the last expression in my post, however, I can't see it

Comment: I see @random's answer - going down this route you have to show somehow that $$(2 k+1) \sum _{j=0}^k \frac{(-1)^j 1^{2 j+1} \binom{k}{j}}{2 j+1}=(2 k) \sum _{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{(-1)^j 1^{2 j+1} \binom{k-1}{j}}{2 j+1} $$